# Get value of PHP array without key name

Tags: php

I need to get a value from an Array like this:

```
array (size=1)
'row_3' => 
  array (size=1)
  'viagem' => 
    array (size=10)
      'veiculo_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'motorista_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'data' => string '2019-06-05' (length=10)
      'destino' => string 'A' (length=1)
      'vrUnit' => string '' (length=0)
      'horaSaida' => string '00:00:00' (length=8)
      'horaChegada' => string '00:00:00' (length=8)
      'kmInicial' => string '' (length=0)
      'kmFinal' => string '' (length=0)
      'autorizado' => string 'A' (length=1)
```

If I use `$var = $_POST['data']['row_3']['viagem']['destino'];` this work.

But the key `['row_3']` is not fixed, the key can be `['row_5']`, `['row_10']`, etc.

So, my question is how I get the value using a code like `$var = $_POST['data']??something??['viagem']['destino'];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$var = $_POST['data'][array_keys($_POST['data'])[0]]['viagem']['destino'];
```

Comment: `$var = $_POST['data'][array_keys($_POST['data'])[0]]['viagem']['destino'];` its works. thanks

Answer (score 1):

`array_column` or multiple level `array_shift` might work here, likely there or four `array_shift`:

```
array_shift(array_shift(array_shift($_POST)))['destino'];
```

Comment: here the result is empty

Comment: I try `$_POST` and `$_POST['data']`

Answer (score 1):

You merely need to access the known keys to the depth of your choosing, then grab the dynamic key with `key()`

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/W52VL))

```
$_POST = [
    'data' => [
        'row_3' => [
            'viagem' => [
                'veiculo_id' => '1',
                'motorista_id' => '1',
                'data' => '2019-06-05',
                'destino' => 'A',
                'vrUnit' => '',
                'horaSaida' => '00:00:00',
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

echo $_POST['data']['row_3']['viagem']['destino'];
echo "\n---\n";
$rowKey = key($_POST['data']);  // no need to generate an entire temporary array of keys
echo $_POST['data'][$rowKey]['viagem']['destino'];
```

Output:

```
A
---
A
```